# intlTelInput usage in Symfony3

Tags: javascript, symfony, intl-tel-input

I want to integrate intlTelInput into my project, but it isn't working :(

Added whole intl-tel-input folder into assets from: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

And inserted an input into view as:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
<script src="/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#phone").intlTelInput({
        utilsScript: "build/js/utils.js"
    });
</script>
```

But, something isn't working... My input field is still empty :(

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `jQuery` looks missing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 200 response for the JS file in your browser? asset just takes care of the web root directory. Likely you put your JS file in the wrong directory.

Comment: Yes, 200 OK status from intlTelInput.js and intlTelInput.css files.